# Change language on start

Tags: encryption, startup, disk, language-support, cryptsetup

So I have disk encryption enabled and when I try to enter the passphrase (I am 100% it is correct) I get cryptsetup failed message.This lead me to believe it is from the language I'm using.I tried messing with capslock but nothing.Tried with Super+Space(which is the combination I use to switch languages) but still nothing.I use English (UK) and Bulgarian.Thanks in advance.

P.S I started having this problem after i upgraded my system from 19.04 to 20.04

Comment: the password failing is in english language or other? whats the gdm3 password language?

Comment: It's supposed to be in english since when I added it there were no other languages installed so the english is failing.